# How to push dynamic id in multi-dimensional array with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

In example, I have two models such as Client and Assessment, and one client have many assessments.

Model Client

```
has_many :assessments
```

Model Assessment

```
belongs_to :client
```

Example: I have 3 clients.

client1 have 3 assessments with id [1, 4, 7]

client2 have 3 assessments with id [2, 5, 8]

client3 have 2 assessments with id [3, 6]

And in query I want to get all clients with all first assessments and continue with second assessments, third assessments, ...

The result from active relation to array should be

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: What do you mean "all first assessments"? The `has_many` association on `Client` is not ordered so there is no "first", unless you mean the assessment with the lowest `id`? Also, could you explain *why* you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `includes` and enjoy with `map`, `zip` and splat operator

```
array = Client.includes(:assessments).map{ |k| k.assesments.pluck(:id)}
first, *other = array
new_array = first.zip(*other).compact
#=>[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```